# Packer’s ansible-local does not fetch packer variables as extra vars

Tags: ansible, packer

I am having a packer code that creates an image on azure. I am using ansible-local provisioner for installing the required tools. I execute the below command

```
packer build -force -var azure_subscription_id=**** -var azure_tennant_id=**** -var azure_application_id=**** -var azure_application_password=**** -var nexus_user=**** -var nexus_password=**** build_packer_azure_image.json
```

However, the ansible local provisioner executes the below comaand as a part of packer provisioner. I need two variables nexus_username and nexus_password to inherit the values from packer command above.

> cd /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible-local/5b04201f-b988-90e6-b769-24822ffc5333 && ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=1 PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ansible-playbook /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible-local/5b04201f-b988-90e6-b769-24822ffc5333/provision.yml --extra-vars "packer_build_name=azure-arm packer_builder_type=azure-arm packer_http_addr=" --extra-vars 'nexus_username= nexus_password=' -c local -i /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible-local/5b04201f-b988-90e6-b769-24822ffc5333/packer-provisioner-ansible-local158977121

As it can be seen, the variables are not getting populated. I am placing the sample code snippets for reference in the packer file for reference.

### Packer variables configuration:

```
{
"variables": {
    "azure_subscription_id": "{{env `azure_subscription_id`}}",
    "azure_tennant_id": "{{env `azure_tennant_id`}}",
    "azure_application_id": "{{env `azure_application_id`}}",
    "azure_application_password": "{{env `azure_application_password`}}",
    "ansible_nexus_user": "{{env `nexus_user`}}",
    "ansible_nexus_password": "{{env `nexus_password`}}"
}
```

### Packer provisioner Configuration:

```
"provisioners": [
    {
    "type": "shell",
    "scripts": [
         "../scripts/install_ansible.sh"
      ]
    },
    {
    "type": "ansible-local",
    "playbook_dir": "../workstation-playbook",
    "playbook_file": "../workstation-playbook/provision.yml",
    "extra_arguments": [ "--extra-vars 'nexus_username={{user `ansible_nexus_user`}} nexus_password={{user `ansible_nexus_password`}}'" ]
    },
    {
     "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .Path }}; {{ .Vars }} sudo -E sh '{{ .Path }}'",
     "inline": [
       "/usr/sbin/waagent -force -deprovision+user && export HISTSIZE=0 && sync"
     ],
     "inline_shebang": "/bin/sh -x",
     "type": "shell"
   }]
}
```

Please help me resolving the issue.

Comment: Try `[ "--extra-vars", "nexus_username={{user \`ansible_nexus_user\`}} nexus_password={{user \`ansible_nexus_password\`}} ]"` in the ansible provisioner part of the packer template instead of your current formatting.

Comment: If you're on Windows I think you need to single quote each k/v pair `-var 'nexus_password=****'`.

Comment: I am executing the command on CentOS 7. Also the ultimate aim is to execute this through Jenkins on Ubuntu. In both scenarios, the behaviour is same

Comment: @Matt Schuchard: I used the snippet in the above comment. It still does not take the variable values in the provisioner

Comment: Well that is unfortunate, but what I wrote is the proper syntax according to the documentation by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. The position of variables needs to be interchanged in variables section.Also i tried to keep the name of the variables on left hand side and right hand side same. It worked